# Getting a warning 'string refs not supported,please use callback' when using csstransition on reaccomponents?

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm getting this warning:

> string refs not supported, please use callback

when using CSS transition on React components.

```
render() {
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup //Timeouts>
        <SomeComponent/>
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
}
```

I wrapped the components in `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is coming from the component

> ReactCSSTransitionGroup

I see there's an issue in regards to this, you can see more [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/29), but basically you can ignore it, unless it's impacting your components (which then you could file a bug on the module)